# Is there oauth based Twitter datasource available for CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

There is one available for old basic authentication which doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub is full of Twitter plugins. Google this:

```
site:github.com twitter cakephp oauth
```

Or, if you feel like writing from scratch: http://code.42dh.com/oauth/
It has a small Twitter example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good intro to this kind of thing, in case you want to write your own, or use Neils plugin.

http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/neil_crookes_-_designing_cakephp_plugins_for_consuming_apis

Answer (score 0):

There is such a project on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/cakephp-twitter-oauth-datasource/ though I don't know whether it still works as it was released around one year ago.