# CakePHP and posting to certain twitter account

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, twitter-oauth

I used cake php with twitter datasource to post some info on a certain twitter account. Twitter changed the authentication method towards oauth.

I can't find an example of a cakephp app, where a certain message is posted in a **certain** twitter account. For example when publishing an article in the site, I want site's twitter account to get updated.

I have read some examples but in these the user accessing the page gets redirected to twitter to be authenticated and to publish something on his/hers account, which is not want I want.

Anybody has an example on that?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Using one access token with OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token) in the Twitter documentation, it describes a single-user use case and avoids the redirect.

Comment: So no matter what you always have to register a new twitter app for your account so as to have tokens, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I do not know if this helps you, but do you read the article from neil crook? [cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/04/12/cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket/)

I think for the first time the user get redirected to twitter to authorize the application... After that you save ‘oauth_token’ and ‘oauth_token_secret’ for further access to the Twitter Api...

But i must say that i have not tried it yet...

Maybe the tipp from David Yell in this question thread [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518909/is-there-oauth-based-twitter-datasource-available-for-cakephp) helps

Comment: as this page states: "OAuth is a great concept. In summary, it allows users of a service (e.g. Twitter) to authorize other parties (your application) access to their accounts on that service, without sharing their password with the other parties." I don't want to authorize my app to use their twitter account, but rather my app to post to my twitter account.