# Cakephp twitter autopost

Tags: cakephp, twitter

I need to post a product details in twitter whenever it is added in my website.I am using Cakephp, and i use twitter datasource available  in book.cakephp.org . It returns a 'Basic authentication is not supported ' message

when i searched it, i get that twitter is now using OAuth, how can i impliment this in my data source?. i did it referring the below url

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1077/An-Example

Anybody please help.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518909/is-there-oauth-based-twitter-datasource-available-for-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cake Book link seems to be out of date and relevant to the time before Twitter implemented OAuth.

I have accomplished what you're trying to do using http://code.42dh.com/oauth/ but this is basically a controller and a component, not a datasource as you asked.

There's a [CakePHP OAuth Datasource](http://code.google.com/p/cakephp-twitter-oauth-datasource/) for CakePHP which might work (I haven't tried it) but you'll need to add the PHP Oauth library too. If you choose to do this, let me know if it works as interacting with Twitter as a datasource makes a lot more sense, <strike>especially as Cake are depreciating components</strike>.

Comment: who told you cake is depreciating components?

Comment: Benedict: You can use that to post automatically. Just put the relevant code in your controller to execute at the same time as you save the post.

Comment: dogmatic69: Sorry, I was thinking of Vendors, not Components. I've edited my post now. BTW, your imap datasource for Cake rocks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created this - it isnt a datasource but it provides a model you can use to accomplish what you need to do:

https://github.com/voycey/CakePHP-Twitter-API-v1.1-Full

You can either use a Shell to have it post automatically or you can just call it in your controller when you add your entity.